# chart.js v2.0.0 redrawing the chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using **chart.js v2** in my application because when I try to use bower to get the latest version it doesn't pull in the dist folder, but that is another issue.

I have created an angular wrapper for this plugin to get it onto my application.
The wrapper looks like this:

```
.controller('ChartController', function () {
    var self = this;

    // Create our chart
    self.init = function (ctx, data, options, type) {

        // Create our config
        var config = angular.extend({}, { type: type || 'bar', data: data, options: options || {} });

        // Create our chart
        self.chart = new Chart(ctx[0], config);
    };
})

.directive('ngChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ChartController',
        scope: {
            data: '=ngChart',
            type: '@',
            options: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch('type', function () {
                controller.init(element, scope.data, scope.options, scope.type);
            });
            scope.$watch('data', function () {
                controller.init(element, scope.data, scope.options, scope.type);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It is very simple as you can see.
In my controller I have this:

```
self.reportType = 'raw';
self.reportTypes = [{ name: 'Raw data', type: 'raw' }, { name: 'Bar chart', type: 'bar' }, { name: 'Line chart', type: 'line' }];
```

And in my view I have this:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="portlet-input input-inline input-small">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="controller.reportType" ng-change="controller.test()" ng-options="type.type as type.name for type in controller.reportTypes">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="controller.list.length && controller.reportType !== 'raw'">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-print><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
    </div>

    <canvas class="print-only screen-only" ng-chart="controller.chartData" type="{{ controller.reportType }}"></canvas>
</div>
```

Currently I only show the chart if the type is not raw.
When I select **line** it will draw a line chart, if I then select **bar** it won't do anything.
I have tried all sort of things to get it to redraw but it doesn't seem to work. The latest suggestion was the extend the config (which is what I am doing in the init method) so to create a copy and then use that config copy to create a new chart.
This didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I modified the data, the chart redrew itself.
So with that in mind, I changed my init method to this:

```
// Create our chart
self.init = function (ctx, data, options, type) {

    // Create our config
    var config = { type: type || 'bar', data: angular.copy(data), options: options || {} };

    // Create our chart
    self.chart = new Chart(ctx[0], config);
};
```

And that worked, it now redraws properly.
I guess that is because it must check to see if the data has changed, if I do a copy then it is always changing.